# Find a probability of Poisson distribution in R

Tags: r, probability, poisson

Can somebody help me how can I calculate a probability p from the Poisson equation (programming in R)? I know that there is the ppois function, but I'm not sure if I'm able to use it here somehow ...
The equation:

[image: the photo of equation]

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far/give us a little more context? Is this homework? Homework is allowed on Stack Overflow, but maybe you can read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and improve your question ...

Comment: Please see the answer to [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `uniroot` + `ppois` like below to solve `p`

```
> (p <- uniroot(function(p) ppois(5, 650 * p) - 0.5, c(0, 1), tol = 1e-10)$root)
[1] 0.008723325
```

and you can verify

```
> ppois(5, 650 * p)
[1] 0.5
```

or

```
> sum(dpois(0:5, 650*p))
[1] 0.5
```